# Display:table and jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

I'm trying to achieve some sort of drop-down menu using jquery toggle, along with css display:table.
The problem is that columns fits only visible elements (which does make sense...), but the result is really crappy as soon as user toggles an hidden element.

Since my english isn't great, plese check the fiddle below, you'll see what I mean...

Thanks in advance
Vincent

```
Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vinny38/L5shouao/17/
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the columns stop resizing by setting a fixed width on the `li` elements. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/u8n4n49f/1/

Comment: Thanks James! I don't really understand why setting to 250px, but it does the job...

Comment: It works because the size is not auto adjusting now, it keeps it at the same size so it doesn't expand like it was doing before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood the question completely but, if you may want to resize the H2 tag to fit the content. You can make it adding this line in the documentReady:

```
$('#downloads h2').width($('div.links').width());
```